# How to compute approximated values concurrently in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

This is probably a question with many possible answers, but I'm asking for the best design, rather than "how can this be done at all".

Let's assume we are implementing a program with a UI that computes Pi. I can hit a "Start" button to start the computation and a "Stop" button to abort the computation, giving me a message box with the highest precision value of Pi computed so far.

I guess the straight forward approach would be starting a Runnable in a new Thread. The runnable computes Pi, and stores the current value in a shared variable, both threads have access to. "Stop" would abort the Thread, and display the shared variable.

I have a feeling this could be implemented more elegantly, though, but I'm not sure how. Maybe using a CompletableFuture?

I'd rather solve this without adding any new libraries to my project, but if you know a library that supports this particularly well, please leave it in the comments.

Obviously, computing Pi will never finish. It would be great though, if the solution also supports e.g. computing the best move in a game of chess. Which will finish, given enough time, but usually has to be aborted, returning the best move so far.

Comment: [use executors](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/)

Comment: @specializt I know about e.g. Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), and I know how to use it with Futures, but I did not find an elegant way to abort it while still returning the approximated value. If you have a code example, or an outline, it would be great if you could add an answer!

Comment: `Future.cancel();`, then get the current value from the actual object?

Comment: @Kayaman, that sounds better than a shared variable, but why do I need to implement a "CallableWithApproximateResult", or something along those lines? Why did the designers of the Java concurrency framework  not think of a "Future.getBestResultSoFar()"? Or did they?

Comment: Why why why. `Future` is a simple interface and they added more functionality in `CompletableFuture`, but asking why someone didn't do something exactly like you want to is really useless in a programming environment. If creating a class is too big of a deal for you, then I'd recommend you switch languages before you really get scared.

Comment: When it comes to language design, I'm just nosy.
When it comes to this particular problem, I simply want the best possible solution. If you think yours is it, please leave me your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Well `Future` came with the original concurrency API at `1.5`. Besides, you're assuming that `getBestResultSoFar()` is a common requirement. I can't see it being very necessary in real applications, whích would usually need to *finish* a calculation. As well as in cases where a "partial" result would be required, it wouldn't be done with a single `Future`.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to your examples of computing Pi or computing the best moves in chess approximately, you approximation algorithm has be iterative in nature. Like random sampling for Pi and MCMC for chess. This lets me think of two appraoches.

### 1. Using a threadsafe flag

Cou can use `AtomicBoolean` which is a threadsafe boolean variable. You need to pass it to your Runnable and make it check its state while computing the approximation. At the same time you button listener which stops the computation is able to set the variable.

### 2. Computing small chunks

The iterative nature of the algorithm makes it possible to split the computation and later aggregate it again. E.g you compute 1000 iterations, you can split it in chunks of 200 iterations compute these 5 chunks and aggregate the result.

I would now suggest to use an `ExecutorCompletionService` and a `TimerTask`. The idea is to compute a small amount of iterations, which take only a short amount of time and repellingly "refill" the `Executor` with new `Runnable`s using the `TimerTask`. Lets say computing 5 runnables would take 1 second your timer task would put 5 Runnables into the Executor every 1 second. When you hit the stop button you would stop spawning and just wait for the pending tasks finish collect their results and have an result.

Ofcourse you also need a variable which tells the `TimerTask` to stop ,after calling the shutdown methof the the completion service, but this one has not to be threadsafe. The additional benefit of this approach is that you computation is concurrent and that you can fully utilize any CPU easily just be spawning more Runnables. Doing this concurrently allows you to compute more in lesser time and obtain better approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how to implement a stoppable task that still delivers a result. Approximating values is a good example but can be ignored for the solution.

A `FutureTask` for example wouldn't work because the contract of those is that they decide themselves when they are done and they can only either have a result or be cancelled.

A shared (e.g. `volatile`) variable sounds reasonable but has it's drawbacks. When updated regularly in a tight loop you might observe worse performance than using a local variable and reading the state of a shared object is only safe when the object is e.g. immutable or one can guarantee otherwise that reading and writing happen in the correct order.

You can also build something with a result-delivery `BlockingQueue` where the computing thread puts the current result (or even regular updates to the result) once interruption is requested.

But the best solution is probably a (shared) `CompletableFuture`. Sort of a single result-item queue but it has nicer semantics for reporting exceptions.

Example:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> sharedFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

Thread computing = new Thread(() -> {
    int value = 1;
    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() &&
                !sharedFuture.isDone()) { // check could be omitted
            value = value * 32 + 7;
        }
        sharedFuture.complete(value);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        sharedFuture.completeExceptionally(t);
    }
});
computing.start();

try {
    Thread.sleep((long) (5000 * Math.random()));
} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
}

computing.interrupt();
System.out.println(sharedFuture.get());
```

http://ideone.com/8bpEGV

Its not really important how you execute that task. Instead of above `Thread` you can also use an `ExecutorService` and then cancel the `Future` instead of interrupting the thread.

Comment: It doesn’t make much sense to put a statement into a `finally` block and rely on it having no effect in the exceptional case due to some other feature. When you put the `complete` invocation at the end of the `try` body block instead, you don’t need a clarifying comment.

Comment: @Holger Good point. I originally had a nested try-catch to eat  `InterruptedException`s that would finally set the last value, but then simplified the example